# Show custom view after person is selected in peoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: ios

I'm running into trouble with what I think is a pretty basic task. Within peoplePickerNavigationController:peoplePicker:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson: i want to show my own view rather than the standard person view. I'm using a Storyboard, but don't think I can simply manually segue to a window here so I'm thinking I need to create a new XIB with a View Controller in it. I'm setting the Class of the View Controller to my custom View Controller in IB. Then in peoplePickerNavigationController:peoplePicker:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson: I'm doing:

```
MyVC *myVC = [[MyVc alloc] initWithNibName:@"XIBFileName" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

In my View Controller initWithNibName gets called, but not viewDidLoad. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `[peoplePickerVC presentModalViewController:myVC]` instead of presenting from self.

The issue is that the peoplepickerviewcontroller will be in the top of the navigation stack. Becuase you wud've presented the peoplepicker from self. As this is the case, you wont be able to present/push from self as its not at the top of the navigation stack.

Otherwise once the peoplepicker has been poped, then you can further present from self.

Comment: Thanks, that worked and your explanation makes sense. Then once I got this working thanks to your answer I realized I really wanted a slide-from-the-right transition style like a navigation controller. :) So in the end what I used was [peoplePickerVC pushViewController:myVC]. I guess sometimes when it feels like you are fighting against the frameworks it means you are doing something wrong. :)